# posix_spawn Linux: How to make children processes not enter zombie state when terminating

Tags: c, linux, posix, spawn, zombie-process

I have one process which spawns other process with posix_spawn(). When the children processes self-terminate they enter into a zombie state, as is the default expected behaviour. I would like them to terminate completely but I haven't been able to achieve it with the use of posix_spawnattr_setflags(). Perhaps I am not using the right flags. Anyone who knows how to do it?

P.S. Preferrably I would like the children processes to be completely detached and independent from the parent process.

Comment: setsid() system call will detach child process from parent, making it an independent process, they will still share stdin/stdout if you did not close them.

Answer (score 3):

By default, a call to either `exit()` or `_exit()` changes the state of the calling process to Zombie if its parent is still alive. To change this, you can use `sigaction()`:

```
#include <signal.h>

struct sigaction arg = {
    .sa_handler=SIG_IGN,
    .sa_flags=SA_NOCLDWAIT // Never wait for termination of a child process.
};

sigaction(SIGCHLD, &arg, NULL);
```

After writing the above code in the parent process, it will never wait for a child, and the child will go into Terminated state after completion, instead of Zombie.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it disables Zombies for all children, as this setting doesn't take effect when creating a child but when a child dies. If you want some of your children to become zombies and others not, then you cannot use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

the parent must wait for its children and read their exit status. from "man wait":

```
A child that terminates, but has not been waited for becomes a "zombie".
The kernel maintains a minimal set of information about the zombie process (PID,
termination status, resource usage information) in order to allow  the parent to later
perform a wait to obtain information about the child.  As long as a zombie is not
removed from the system via a wait, it will consume a slot in the kernel process
table, and if this table fills, it will not be possible to create further
processes.
If a parent process terminates, then its "zombie" children (if any) are adopted by
init(8), which automatically performs a wait to remove the zombies.

POSIX.1-2001 specifies that if the disposition of SIGCHLD is set to SIG_IGN or the
SA_NOCLDWAIT flag is set for SIGCHLD (see sigaction(2)), then children that terminate 
do not become zombies and a call to wait() or  waitpid() will  block until all 
children have terminated, and then fail with errno set to ECHILD.  (The original POSIX 
standard left the behavior of setting SIGCHLD to SIG_IGN unspecified.  Note that even 
though the default disposition of SIGCHLD is "ignore", explicitly setting the 
disposition to SIG_IGN results in different treatment of zombie process children.)  
Linux 2.6 conforms to this specification.  However, Linux 2.4 (and earlier)  does  
not:  if  a wait()  or  waitpid()  call  is made while SIGCHLD is being ignored, the 
call behaves just as though SIGCHLD were not being ignored, that is, the call blocks 
until the next child terminates and then returns the process ID and status of that 
child.
```

Comment: He wants to do what you used to do with a double `fork()` in the past. Prior to `posix_spawn` you had to `fork`+`exec` and here existed the trick of a double fork. You fork child A and child A forks child B, now you let child A die and clean it up. The result was that child B lost its parent and was now adopted by the PID 1 process (init or systemd), which performed the zombie clean up for you, so the process didn't have to clean up child B itself and child B could even survive the processes it started.